# How can I separate the individual members of a class within a dataframe and then return them by name?

Tags: python, class, dataframe

I created a dataframe from the following excel sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dMMW.jpg

Each row is a singular "mon" with its own specific stats. I created a class for the mons, but now I am unsure how to separate them and call them individually by name.

Eventually, I'd like to be able to call Mon 1 and Mon 2 and create a new class that would contain the logic for them to battle based on their stats.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\Simulator.xlsx')

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    print(row)
```

Comment: why use `pandas` at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thought that was the best option to import the excel data. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does it **need** to be an xlsx? Will not a simple `.csv` suffice? If so, just use the `csv` module.

Comment: can you share the spreadsheet for google docs rather than the image? It would help in testing for an answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I could save it as a csv. From there do I use DictWriter?

Comment: @EB_Crypto well, you can use a `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader` if you'd like. But sticking with `pandas`, something like `[Mon(r.Name, r.HP, r.PA, r.PD, r.SA, r.SD, r.SPD, r.Type1, r.Type2, r.A1, r.A2, r.A3) for r in df.itertuples()]` would also work. Now you have a list of `Mon` objects

Comment: @oppressionslayer sure, what is the best way to share?

Comment: When you open in google docs, there's a blue share button on the type right. You can share it as readonly and it gives a link.

Comment: @oppressionslayer here's the link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUp_JiGHFac36nc3HTMcmAFzVPak29Uls_DBiz_F-zA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @oppressionslayer edited the code a little bit as well

Answer (score 1):

Use df.iterrows() and create an instance of the class for each row.

Comment: I edited the post. With that code I was able to separate each row. From here, how would you suggest I create the instance for the class for each row?

Comment: Do you know how to create instances of a class? Just feed the elements of row (accessed like a list, with brackets) into the initializer.

Comment: do I need to do it for every single row name, not sure what the most efficient way is? I'm relatively new